# Ajax post throws A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to secure my ajax posts using the anti-forgery mechanism.

First I've added the antiforgerytoken helper method call to my view

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

and then adjusted my jquery post call

```
var values = $(this).serialize() + "&__RequestVerificationToken=" + $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

$.post(url, values)
    .success(page.submitSuccess)
    .error(page.submitError)
    .complete(page.submitComplete);
```

and of course I decorated my action method with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ProjectCreateCommand command)
{
    ....
}
```

but after submiting the form it throws the *A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid* error.

I've deleted the token cookie and also I've restarted the browser.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `$(form).serialize();` it will serialize all input tags, so you can do it by the $.post jquery method. Try something like this:

```
$("#you_form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $(this).attr("action"), // get url from action attribute, your route setted by the Html.BeginForm()
       data: $(this).serialize(), // serialize all input tags from this form
       success: page.submitSuccess; 
    });
});
```

There is no problem using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, serialize method will add this together.

Take a look at this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I forgot to mention, the hidden input is outside the form.

Comment: Can you put it into the form? It have to be into the form to be serialize correctly.

Comment: there was an error on this code, I've corrected. What error message did you take?

Comment: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid